# Hosting NET Core only with IIS without Kestrel and Http.sys

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

Im a beginner in microsoft architecture.

For a project I am asked to host a net core web application on an IIS server by removing the use of the kestrel server (http.sys too). 
**The net core application must only run via IIS**.

But according to my research via Microsoft documentation, blogs and forums. It seems to me that a net core application must implement Kestrel or http.sys because it runs in an independent process. And that IIS allows to complete the features of the Kestrel server.

Is there a way to host a net core microservices application on IIS without Kestrel and Http.sys?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can only wait till .NET Core 2.2, where IIS integration is simplified. However, "Kestrel" and http.sys are components you won't be able to "go without". http.sys is used by IIS to talk HTTP, while Kestrel is both a web server, and the HTTP pipeline for ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, IIS serves as a reverse proxy only. Kestrel is absolutely required. HTTP.sys is an alternative to using IIS, but either way Kestrel is what runs the Core app.

Comment: That's what I thought.